# how to change picker-item-active class in ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am trying to change the styles of a calendar from ion-datetime. I can see in the source that it has an .:host .picker-item-active class which it want to change the colour, however this does not work.

```
:host .picker-item-active {
   color: var(--ion-color-base);
}
```

i tried to add !important, but still no change

```
:host .picker-item-active {
       color: green !important;
    }
```

any ideas?

Comment: ::ng-deep .picker-item-active

Answer (score 0):

Which version of ionic do you use?
To change the color of a picker item selected i do that

```
.picker-opt-selected {
    color: green!important;
}
```

But remember to put it in your `global.scss`

Comment: im using the latest verison